# Redirect user page to user/edit and user/login

Tags: routes, users, redirection

I want to do page redirect when user access **/user** page. When user anonymous user access the /user it should redirect to user/login page and when logged in user access the /user page it should redirect to user/%/edit page.

I have tried the following the code

```
function my_user_menu_alter(&$items){
   $items['user']['page callback'] = 'my_user_page_redirect';
} 
function my_user_page_redirect() {
  global $user;
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
  drupal_goto('user/'.$user->uid.'/edit');
}
 else {
   drupal_goto('user/login');
 }

}
```

For logged in user it redirects to user/%/edit page. For anonymous user it displays webpage redirect error[image]

How can I do this. Thank You

Comment: From user to user/login already happens for anonymous users. Drupal does that without any third-party modules.

Comment: I have custom login form.

Comment: It's not the login form that does that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `hook_menu_alter`, achieve it in `hook_init`, try something like  (don't forget changes in hook_init need clear the cache to getting applied)

```
function yourmodule_init(){
   if(current_path()=="user"){
   global $user;
     if (user_is_logged_in()) {
      drupal_goto('user/'.$user->uid.'/edit');
    }
   else {
      drupal_goto('user/login');
   }
}
}
```